# How to limit zooming of a vis.js network?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I've implemented a simple network using vis.js. Here's my code:

```
//create an array of nodes
var nodes = [
    {
        id: "1",
        label: "item1"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        label: "item2"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        label: "item3"
    },
];

// create an array with edges
var edges = [
    {
        from: "1",
        to: "2",
        label: "relation-1",
        arrows: "from"
    },
    {
        from: "1",
        to: "3",
        label: "relation-2",
        arrows: "to"
    },
];

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

// provide the data in the vis format
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {};

// initialize your network!
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

On performing the zoom-out operation multiple times the network disappears. Are there any functions to limit the zooming level?

Comment: If totallytypicalcow's answer helps (and it looks like it solves your issue), don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick symbol on the left. Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote you some code to get this function working since there is no zoomMax function within the network of vis.js, I wrote some basic logic to help you out.

```
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var afterzoomlimit = { //here we are setting the zoom limit to move to 
    scale: 0.49,
}

var options = {}; 

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
network.on("zoom",function(){ //while zooming 
    if(network.getScale() <= 0.49 )//the limit you want to stop at
    {
        network.moveTo(afterzoomlimit); //set this limit so it stops zooming out here
    } 
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/styb8u9o/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version that preserves the last position, to prevent an annoying jump or slow pan when you get to the maximum extent.

```
let MIN_ZOOM = 0.5
let MAX_ZOOM = 2.0
let lastZoomPosition = {x:0, y:0}
network.on("zoom",function(params){
    let scale = network.getScale()
    if(scale <= MIN_ZOOM )
    {
        network.moveTo({
            position: lastZoomPosition,
            scale: MIN_ZOOM
        });
    }
    else if(scale >= MAX_ZOOM ){
        network.moveTo({
            position: lastZoomPosition,
            scale: MAX_ZOOM,
       });
     }
     else{
        lastZoomPosition = network.getViewPosition()
     }
});
network.on("dragEnd",function(params){
    lastZoomPosition = network.getViewPosition()
});
```

Still, it will be redundant once the following issue is resolved:
https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/574

Comment: Thanks @cmuk ! Tested on vis-network-9.1.2.  This is the only solution that does not produce jitter or panning when reaching zoom limit.  IMO this should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 5):

***You can use this code is better because you will never go to the middle of the network when you reach the zoom limit:***

```
//NetWork on Zoom
network.on("zoom",function(){
   pos = [];
   pos = network.getViewPosition();

   if(network.getScale() <= 0.49 )
   {

    network.moveTo({
        position: {x:pos.x, y:pos.y},
        scale: 0.49,
      });
   }
   if(network.getScale() >= 2.00 ){

        network.moveTo({
        position: {x:pos.x, y:pos.y},
        scale: 2.00,
      });
    }
  });
```