# Is there a way to zoom out only a few times from a vis.js network?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am using react-graph-vis and when I zoom out of the created network, the network disappears and you have to refresh the page to show it again, after reading the documentation and viewing online examples I couldn't find a way to prevent this behaviour, so is there a way to zoom out of a network a fixed number of times so that you don't zoom out entirely or currently there is no way to prevent this behaviour in vis.js?

Comment: you can try to limit vis network zoom, check out both answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299774/how-to-limit-zooming-of-a-vis-js-network,